# Why my text in li do not center horizontally？

Tags: html, css

Why does my text in an `<li>` element not center horizontally？

[image]

the `ul` and `li`'s CSS is below, I have set `horiz-align: center;` in the `li`:

```
#banner ul{

    list-style: none;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
}

#banner ul li {

    float: left;
    margin: auto 0;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    horiz-align: center;
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as horizon-align. You're looking for text-align.

Comment: Out of interest, how did you discover "horiz-align"?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `text-align` to set the align:

```
text-align:center;
```

`text-align` stipulate the text in the element's alignment.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Make it `text-align` to `center`

```
text-align:center;


#banner ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: auto 0;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```